# Pass integer value through pthread_create

Tags: c, pthreads

I simply want to pass the value of an integer to a thread.

How can I do that?

I tried:

```
    int i;
    pthread_t thread_tid[10];
    for(i=0; i<10; i++)
    {
        pthread_create(&thread_tid[i], NULL, collector, i);
    }
```

The thread method looks like this:

```
    void *collector( void *arg)
    {
        int a = (int) arg;
    ...
```

I get the following warning:

```
    warning: cast from pointer to integer of different size [-Wpointer-to-int-cast]
```

Answer (score 7):

The compiler will complain if you don't cast `i` to a void pointer:

```
pthread_create(&thread_tid[i], NULL, collector, (void*)i);
```

That said, casting an integer to a pointer isn't strictly safe:

> ISO/IEC 9899:201x
>   6.3.2.3 Pointers
>
> 5. An integer may be converted to any pointer type. Except as previously specified, the result is implementation-defined, might not be correctly aligned, might not point to an entity of the referenced type, and might be a trap representation.

so you're better off passing a separate pointer to each thread.

Here's a full working example, which passes each thread a pointer to a separate element in an array:

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void * collector(void* arg)
{
    int* a = (int*)arg;
    printf("%d\n", *a);
    return NULL;
}

int main()
{
    int i, id[10];
    pthread_t thread_tid[10];

    for(i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        id[i] = i;
        pthread_create(&thread_tid[i], NULL, collector, (void*)(id + i));
    }

    for(i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        pthread_join(thread_tid[i], NULL);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

There's a nice intro to pthreads [here](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~travitch/pthreads_primer.html).

Comment: Didn't work for me. Got uninitialized indexes. This did the job though:         
pthread_create(&thread_tid[i], NULL, collector, (void*)(id[i]));

Answer (score 1):

int is 32 bit, and void * is 64 bit in 64bit Linux; In that case you should use long int instead of int;

```
long int i;
pthread_create(&thread_id, NULL, fun, (void*)i);
```

int fun(void *i) function

```
 long int id = (long int) i;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
void *foo(void *i) {
    int a = *((int *) i);
    free(i);
}

int main {
    int *arg = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char))
    pthread_create(&thread, 0, foo, arg);
}
```

Comment: `malloc` missing

Answer (score 1):

It better to use of a `struct` for send more parameters in one :

```
struct PARAMS
{
    int i;
    char c[255];
    float f;
} params;

pthread_create(&thread_id, NULL, fun, (void*)(&params));
```

then you can `cast` `params` to `PARAMS*` and use of it in `pthread` `routine`:

```
PARAMS *p = static_cast<PARAMS*>(params);
p->i = 5;
strcpy(p->c, "hello");
p->f = 45.2;
```